# Liferay : How to show a Configured Page once User Enters Valid Credentials

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1 version .

Once a User enters `http:localhost` , i am displaying my Web Page called "/ravi" which consists of my Custom Portal as shown

I have configured this below properties under portal-ext.properties as shown

```
auth.forward.by.last.path=true
default.landing.page.path=/web/guest/ravi
```

Please see the screen shot of my Custom Portlet shown when the users enters http:localhost

[image]

Now my requirement is that i need to show another page ("/web/guest/test") if he enters valid crendentails .

In my processAction class , i am doing this way

```
public class ValidateUser extends MVCPortlet {
    public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {

        String userName = (String) request.getParameter("userName");
                String password = (String) request.getParameter("password");
        try {
//  Contatcs DB and validates the credentials here 
// Please let me know how can i show the Configured Page if his credentials are valid ??
        } 
               catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }


}
```

**Edited Part**

Thank you very much for the answer with respect to the default login.events.post .

I am new to Liferay , so i may be doing a mistake here , so please help me if i was doing anything wrong .

I followed these steps :

1. Created a New Portlet named "MyLogon"  Portlet and  in its view.jsp created a form with two text fields (Login and Password ) and a submit button .
   On click of that Submit Button , i was actually calling my processAction Method and making a DB call to validate Users from mysql db .

2.Then i created a page inside /web/guest/ravi   and added this "MyLogon" Portlet  to this new  page /web/guest/ravi

3. Then configured this below properties under `portal-ext.properties`

   auth.forward.by.last.path=true
   default.landing.page.path=/web/guest/ravi

This is what i did .

And when entering `http:localhost:8080` , it displayed taht page .

Please tell me if i am doing anything wrong

**Edited 2nd Part**

I have understood some part of your answer and i have these questions .
Could you please help

I need to validate Users based on the Data present inside my DataBase , so for this i need to do the below thins .

1. I need to create a Hook , to overdide this property

   login.events.pre=com.LoginAction

   public class LoginAction extends Action {

   ```
   public void run(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
   ```

   // Here i need to make a Database call to validate User Credentials and then do redirect him to the page i wanted ??

   ```
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a [Hook](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-a-ho-4) and override the default [login.events.post](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/performing-a-custom-acti-4)

Below code for your reference,

```
public class LandingPageAction extends Action {
    public LandingPageAction()
        {

        }
 public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ActionException
  {
      try
      {
          doRun(request, response);
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          throw new ActionException(e);
      }
  }

protected void doRun(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
  {
String homeRedirect="/web/guest/test";
LastPath lastPath = new LastPath(StringPool.BLANK, homeRedirect); 
session.setAttribute("LAST_PATH", lastPath);
  }
}
```

There are few things which I don't understand here. You are hitting localhost:8080, but screen shot shows that you are already logged in (there is a SignOut link and user Ravi Kiran is already logged in), but still there is a login page shown.

`default.landing.page.path` comes into picture when you are *loggedin* user. Are you hitting localhost:8080 or localhost/web/guest/Ravi ? You are not logged in yet, so it should not redirect to /web/guest/Ravi.

You could reuse the default Authentication code in Liferay. Not sure why you are taking User credentials from request parameters and making DB call yourself.

**Edited as per the update in the question**

`1.` The default Login Page of Liferay (the one that you see when you freshly download and hit localhost:8080 comes from this path
`..\default\deploy\ROOT.war\html\portlet\login`.
There is a `login.jsp` in this path which you can edit and give your own look and feel.
You can find below entry in this `login.jsp` page 
`<portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/login/login" />`

This has a corresponding entry in ../deploy/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml

```
<action path="/login/login" type="com.liferay.portlet.login.action.LoginAction">
    <forward name="portlet.login.login" path="portlet.login.login" />
</action>
```

You can open up the source code and look into `com.liferay.portlet.login.action.LoginAction` method.
This performs a basic Authentication as per your `passwords.encryption.algorithm=` and `passwords.digest.encoding=` 
configuration in `portal-ext.properties` file. `LoginAction` will perform basic authentication and will redirect all 
users as per path mentioned in `default.landing.page.path=` 
If you want (some) Users to redirect to (some) other path(conditionally), you can use the code I have mentioned above by writing a Hook.

`2.` Once authenticated, you can login and create a Page (in your case its "ravi"). You can add your custom Portlet to this Page. You should not write a cutom portlet which will do authentication once *you are already logged in*

Comment: Thanks for the response , please see the edited part in my question . please let me know if i am making any mistake .

Comment: Hi Vikas , Thank you very very much for the clear explanation .
I have overlooked things on my End . Liferay seems very confusing to me and documents assumes every body is master .
I have understood some part of your answer and i have these questions .
Could you please help . I have edited my question (See 2nd Part ) in my question .